# Add fee to Woocommerce Shipping Class without the use of zones or flat rate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and a plugin called Table Rate Shipping Plus (by mangohour) for our simple non-profit comic bookstore. We use weight based shipping as a standard in Sweden, so the flat rate system is not an option for our shop.

I have created a 'bulky' shipping class and I would need it to, upon choosing products in that class, automatically add a small fee to the cart (only once, without stacking) without the use of woocommerce's shipping zones and the flat rate system.

I can't seem to find anything that does this simple act anywhere, and I'm not php-savvy enough to be able to write functions or filters for the functions.php myself.

How can this be done?

Comment: You'll have to show us the code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: If I'm clear, whenever someone adds a product from the "bulky" shipping class, a small fee gets added to the cart (just once not multiple times for multiple products)?
I think I have an idea of what you're asking. Let me see if I can get something going, but could you clarify your question a bit, so I'm clear about what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I gave you this code to put in functions.php, would you understand how to customize it? Or should I turn it into a simple plugin for you?

**Heres a visual of it working on my local WP testing environment.**

[image: Imgur]

---

**Installing into functions.php**

Scroll down to where the actual code begins, and copy and paste that entire block, right onto the very bottom of your theme folders functions.php. Just a simple copy and paste.

---

**Instructions for using.**

Step 1. Create your shipping classes within WooComerce Settings > Shipping > Shipping Classes. For example on my test site I created 'bulky' and 'light' shipping classes within wooComerce settings. Remember the slug you set for step 2.

Step 2. At `EX1` I place the case sensitive slug of a WooCommerce shipping class wrapped in ''.
At `EX2` I place the description for the fee you would like displayed at checkout within ''. Finnaly at `EX3` you simply place the numeric value for the fee, this does not go within ''.

```
//Example:
$shippingClasses['EX1'] = ['description' => 'EX2', 'fee' => EX3];

//How it will look:
$shippingClasses['bulky'] = ['description' => 'Bulky Fee', 'fee' => 7];
$shippingClasses['light'] = ['description' => 'Light Fee', 'fee' => 4];
```

And thats it! Thats all you have to do.

---

**Code**

```
function fees_fees_fees() {

    $shippingClasses['bulky'] = ['description' => 'Bulky Fee', 'fee' => 5];
    $shippingClasses['light'] = ['description' => 'Light Fee', 'fee' => 7];

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $shipping_class = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_shipping_class' );

        foreach($shippingClasses as $key => $val) {
        if ( isset( $shipping_class[0]->slug ) && in_array( $shipping_class[0]->slug, [$key] ) ) {
              WC()->cart->add_fee( __($val['description'], 'woocommerce'), $val['fee'] ); }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'fees_fees_fees' );
```

Comment: I’m glad it works for you! Feel free to take a little time to test it out. If you find a bug or so, just let me know in a comment here, and I’ll take a look! I might be packaging this script up into a plug-in. I’ll send you a GitHub link to it if I do.

Comment: Yes, I will! The shop will go live again in a week and I'll test and troubleshoot and get back to you! GitHub link, yes! Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I thought I'd let you know I found the time to make a simple plugin out of this. It adds a field to the shipping class table for the "fee". Here it's on github.  https://github.com/iambrennanwalsh/woo-shipping-class-fees

Comment: Thank you! I think this will help a lot of people! My coworker  just realized that I did not really solve the issue with a shipping class fee. Stupidly I thought I needed to add a bulky fee to a shipping class, and this solving my problem, but I should’ve asked how to add a bulky fee automatically to the cart if the height of the products is over 2,9 cm. Is it too much to ask if you could adapt/extend the function/plugin? I don’t want to be rude and waste your time. If not I still appreciate this solution and I will use it until I figure my new problem out.