# Add fee to WooCommerce shipping class but exclude local pickup

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, fee

I'm using [Add fee to Woocommerce Shipping Class without the use of zones or flat rate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54835254/11987538) answer code, that allows me add an additional 'Fee' if any product from the 'Dangerous Goods' shipping class has been added to cart.

This is great as it allows me to cover the additional costs associated to packaging/shipping, however it is also adding the 'fee' when users select 'Local Pickup' shipping option.

I would love to exclude  'Local Pickup' from the additional fee if selected.

Therefore i use:

```php
function fees_fees_fees() {

    $shippingClasses['dangerous-goods'] = ['description' => 'Dangerous Goods Fee', 'fee' => 130];

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $shipping_class = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_shipping_class' );

        foreach($shippingClasses as $key => $val) {
        if ( isset( $shipping_class[0]->slug ) && in_array( $shipping_class[0]->slug, [$key] ) ) {
              WC()->cart->add_fee( __($val['description'], 'woocommerce'), $val['fee'] ); }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'fees_fees_fees' );
```

However, I'm stuck on the next step. Any adivce?

Answer (score 1):

- The use of `WC()->cart` is not necessary, as `$cart` is already passed to the callback function
- `WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )` can be used to get the chosen shipping method, then it is a matter of adding an if condition

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Get chosen shipping method
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_method = substr( $chosen_shipping_methods[0], 0, strpos( $chosen_shipping_methods[0], ':' ) );

    // NOT for local pickup
    if ( $chosen_shipping_method != 'local_pickup' ) {
        // Settings
        $shipping_classes['dangerous-goods'] = [ 'description' => 'Dangerous Goods Fee', 'fee' => 130 ];

        // Loop though cart items
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $shipping_class = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_shipping_class' );
    
            foreach ( $shipping_classes as $key => $val ) {
                if ( isset( $shipping_class[0]->slug ) && in_array( $shipping_class[0]->slug, [$key] ) ) {
                    $cart->add_fee( __( $val['description'], 'woocommerce' ), $val['fee'] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Brilliant - this works perfectly as I have described!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add check to slug.

```php
 if ( isset( $shipping_class[0]->slug ) && in_array( $shipping_class[0]->slug, [$key] )  &&  $shipping_class[0]->slug != 'local_pickup') {
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried replacing line 9 with the code suggested - but it hasn't removed the fee when toggling to 'Local Pickup'.